# Sockets in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm working on a project that requires me to connect to an outside server from my oculus app, I want to do this via pushing a button. I have pretty limited C# knowledge, and would like someone to check my code. I can click the button just fine but initiating the connection doesn't seem to work.

```
  using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

     namespace Client

     {

     }

      public class ConnectionCSClient : MonoBehaviour
    {
    }
    public class Click : MonoBehaviour
    {

    }
class Program
{
    public Button ConnectButton;

    void Start()
    {
        Button Button = ConnectButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        ConnectButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick); //Adds a listner on the button
    }
    void TaskOnClick()

    {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                Debug.Log("Pressed left click.");
            }
          if (ConnectButton.onClick = true) try static void ExecuteClient();

            {
                { 

            // Establish the remote endpoint
            // for the socket. This example
            // uses port 11111 on the local
            // computer.
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11111);

            // Creation TCP/IP Socket using
            // Socket Class Constructor
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                // Connect Socket to the remote
                // endpoint using method Connect()
                sender.Connect(localEndPoint);

                // We print EndPoint information
                // that we are connected
                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to -> {0} ",
                              sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Creation of message that
                // we will send to Server
                byte[] messageSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test Client<EOF>");
                int byteSent = sender.Send(messageSent);

                // Data buffer
                byte[] messageReceived = new byte[1024];

                // We receive the message using
                // the method Receive(). This
                // method returns number of bytes
                // received, that we'll use to
                // convert them to string
                int byteRecv = sender.Receive(messageReceived);
                Console.WriteLine("Message from Server -> {0}",
                      Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageReceived,
                                                 0, byteRecv));

                // Close Socket using
                // the method Close()
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();
            }
            // Manage of Socket's Exceptions
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }

            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
                }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you format your code first ... we see a bunch of empty namespaces and classes here ... what are they good for? And your `class Program` is not a `MonoBehaviour` .. so how should `Start` be ever called? Also have in mind that your socket methods are all synchronous => if you manage to get `TaskOnClick` called directly by the button click, the entire application will freeze until the method finishes ... something absolutely undesirable in an XR application ;)

Comment: And then further why not simply use a `TcpClient` instead of manually handling a socket? And note that TCP is a stream-based protocol .. there is no build-in "message" but packages .. you will either need to receive until you get a certain "end of message" character/string or you need to go by byte length and on the sender side prepend the message length first and start with receiving that.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: if you really want to use websockets, then i can highly recommend this library: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/best-http-2-155981#description

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you need to work at the level of TCP sockets for this? That would be like opening up and removing the entire dashboard of your car just because the radio isn't working. You don't need to do that. HTTP is built on top of TCP and so HTTP is what you would use for *web* requests.

Unity provides the [WebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) class specifically for communicating with *web* servers.